# NHibernate lazy loading but no virtual properties?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lazy-loading

I'm experiencing something rather odd. I'm tinkering with NHibernate 3.2 mapping by code and have a very simple object model I'm using just to play.

None of my properties in the entire model are marked as virtual because I dont want lazy loading. I'm mapping by code and in each class mapping I'm setting `Lazy(false);`

However when it comes to mapping collections, if I try and access a collection after the session has ended I get an error `"failed to lazily initialize a collection of role..."`.

I have to explicitly set `collectionMapping.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);` before it will eager load the collection. It was my understanding that lazy loading was not possible unless your properties in your model were defined at virtuals?

Have I fundamentally missed something?

Comment: Recommended read: [NHibernate is lazy, just live with it](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual properties and methods are only needed for lazy associations (many-to-one or one-to-one) because NHibnerate needs to set a proxy **entity** on the association property.

Collections (one-to-many and many-to-many) don't need any virtual properties because only the **collection** is lazy, not the entities in the collection. NHibernate will always use its own collection classes, even if you disable lazy loading.

Answer (score 7):

`virtual` is needed more than just for lazy loading. NHibernate requires them to be `virtual` because it creates a run-time proxy of the class and injects behavior.

Comment: How is it though that it is essentially performing lazy loading when if I set `Lazy(true);` it will error telling me to set all my properties to virtual?

Comment: ... but the proxy is only used for lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to use `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`, because NH needs its own collection implementation.

Consider:

- You won't get very far in a complex model without lazy loading, except your database fits into RAM or you don't mind to cut you OO model into pieces which destroys both maintainability and performance.
- You can have entities without virtual members when you use interfaces to create proxies from. However, you should only use these interfaces to reference to entities, because they could always be proxies.

Comment: Valid points, however I can lazy load without setting all my properties as virtual. I didn't think that was possible in NHibernate.